# java interface references downcasting

Tags: java, interface

```
    interface A {}

    interface B{}

    interface C{}

    A a = new A(){};
    B b = (B)a;
    C c = (C)b;
```

Even Though these interfaces are not related , the above code seems to compile ,If i change these interfaces to classes , it doesn't compile for obvious reasons . Why do interfaces behave this way

Comment: Try making `A` or `B` (and `C`) incompatible (instead of simple marker interfaces). In Java, **everything** (that isn't a primitive value) *inherits* from `java.lang.Object`

Comment: I have made the following change . interface A {
 void test();
}

interface B{
 void fun();
}

interface C{
 void hi();
}  Still same issue . Also everything extending from java.lang.Object isn't a reasonable explanation , because if i change these interfaces to classes it does give the expected compilation error

Comment: "incompatible" would be having a `test()` method in all three interfaces, but with different (and incompatible) return types.

Comment: @Thilo - I did make the return types incompatible with all three interfaces having a test method . But still the code compiles . So incompatibility doesn't seem to be the explanation here . Please correct me if i am wrong . However the multiple inheritance reasoning that you've given below starts making sense

Comment: *"it doesn't compile for obvious reasons"* Not obvious to the compiler. The compiler just sees that you cast `A` to a `B` or `A` to a `C`. It doesn't know what's actually in `a` or `b`. (What if `a` was the parameter to a method?) *"Why do interfaces behave this way"* The way interfaces behave is actually the norm. Classes behave the way they do because the compiler has more information and can look at the hierarchy. Sometimes the compiler can tell that a particular cast will never succeed but it's the exception to the rule. Most of the time the compiler doesn't know and lets you do the cast.

Comment: All the comments which i've been making is on the following premise , "While downcasting X to Y the compiler should check whether X and Y belong to the same inheritance tree " . But now i am beginning to see that it is a just decision for the compiler to go ahead with the casting because of the multiple inheritance feature supported by interfaces . But , someone please clarify Thilo's comment about casting StringBuilder to Number . It just doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interfaces are unrelated, but there could be classes that implement all three interfaces, so there could be instances that can be cast around merrily.

The reason it does not work with classes is that a given class can extend only one superclass, so there cannot be any class that extends both `class A` and `class B`.

Another spin on this are `final` classes. You cannot cast, for example, `String` to `Map` because there can be no subclasses of `String` that implement `Map`. But you can cast `Date` or `ArrayList` to `Map` because there could be subclasses that fit.

Note that this reasoning only applies at compile-time. An invalid cast will still fail at run-time. The compile-time type-checking is supposed to catch invalid casts as much as possible, but not all cases can be detected by static type checking (at least not in Java). So unless the compiler can guarantee that your cast makes no sense, it will allow it.

Comment: Do you mean to say , the following would compile ? StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
  Number n = (Number)b; . It doesn't

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It does not compile, because `StringBuilder` is `final` (which I did not expect). Updating the example.

Comment: Good point about final and non-final classes.  I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

I think what Eliot is trying to say is that these casts *could* succeed if the initial assignment was different.

```
class MyClass implements A, B, C {}

interface A {}

interface B{}

interface C{}

A a = new MyClass();
B b = (B)a;
C c = (C)b;
```

Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, that's why it **can't** work with classes.  But since interfaces can be multiply implemented, the syntax is potentially OK.

Comment: But A , B  & C are unrelated right , Isn't the same hierarchy principle applicable while downcasting ? . How can i downcast something to something which is totally unrelated

Comment: They aren't unrelated if they all appear in the same class.  Then they're *the same class.*  Look at my code (which I admit I didn't attempt to compile, so if you find an error let me know).

Comment: Your code does compile , so does the one i've posted initially as the question , which is what puzzles me :) . I ve moved A B and C outside of this class . Still the code compiles . Why is it so

Comment: My code compiles and runs without error (or it should).  That's why it's allowed, because it could work with interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon my comment, if the interfaces are *compatible* then your code might well succeed at runtime. But, if the interfaces are *incompatible* then you could experience catastrophic run-time errors. For example,

```
interface A {
    int doIt(int a);
}

interface B {
    float doIt(float b);
}
```

If you then provide an **implementation**<sup>1</sup>

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A() {
        public int doIt(int a) {
            return 2 * a;
        }
    };
    B b = (B) a;
    System.out.println(b.doIt(1));
}
```

At compile time, the compiler trusts that you know what you're doing. And happily allows you to cast `a` to `B` (and then assign to `b`). But, at runtime you get `java.lang.ClassCastException` because the interfaces are incompatible.

<sup>1<sub>`a` is just another `java.lang.Object` instance, which happens to implement interface `A`</sub></sup>